# TypeError: Beautifulsoap() takes no arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, beautifulsoup

i have this problem in mac:
Beautifulsoup() takes no arguments.

Comment: Can you provide your source code?

Comment: I can assure you that BeaufitulSoup can take arguments *even* on a Mac.

Comment: You should edit your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740394/typeerror-beautifulsoap-takes-no-arguments-in-macos) instead of asking a new one that's missing *all* the details from the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of: [TypeError: Beautifulsoap() takes no arguments. => in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740394/typeerror-beautifulsoap-takes-no-arguments-in-macos)

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-4276125/%D9%82%D9%87%D9%88%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-ha120'
res = requests.get(url)
if res.status_code == 200:
    dom = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    element = dom.select('div.js-price-value')
    if element:
        element = element[0]
        print(element.text)
```

You should get

```
                ۷۷۷,۲۰۰
```

You need to import the correct library `BeautifulSoup`(capital B and S) instead of Beautifulsoap. Also, the `html.parse` should be replaced with `html.parser`. If you're using the libraries in another language make sure your imports are consistent with the documentation.

Comment: Where did you get all that stuff from? The OP didn't even post their code.

Comment: As specified, this is an extension of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740394/typeerror-beautifulsoap-takes-no-arguments-in-macos

Comment: The previous question was closed so I cannot post an answer...:)

Comment: This is not an *extension*. Asking the same question after getting it closed is against the rules here. The OP should edit the initial question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. Thank you for the note. Should I delete my answer then...?